# Cannot lower mysql threads

Tags: server, mysql

I am running a LAMP stack on my ubuntu server. But it keeps running out of memory because of mysql.

It spawns 38 processes. I am failing to lower the amount of threads.
I tried setting the `max_connections` to 4 and the `thread_cache_size` to 2, but still it spawns the 38 threads:
[ProccessList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RGsS.png)

The mysql status does show only 2 worker threads are spawned:

```
+------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                | Value |
+------------------------------+-------+
| Delayed_insert_threads       | 0     |
| Mysqlx_worker_threads        | 2     |
| Mysqlx_worker_threads_active | 0     |
| Slow_launch_threads          | 0     |
| Threads_cached               | 0     |
| Threads_connected            | 1     |
| Threads_created              | 1     |
| Threads_running              | 2     |
+------------------------------+-------+
```

Any suggestions to lower the amount of threads?

Comment: Threads are rarely the issue when you’re running out of memory with MySQL. What is the exact error message you see in `/var/log/mysql/error.log` when the system runs out of memory?

Comment: There is nothing in the error file. The system just stops responding and I have to reboot the entire system.